# A question about amplifying low level strain gauge voltages

Tags: strain-gage

I'm having difficulty in deciding about implementing an amplifier and whether I need it at all for a strain gauge. I never dealt with such situation before and would be very glad to have your opinions.

I will have the following strain_gauges: http://bridgetest.com/wp-content/uploads/ST350-Operations-Manual-v2.2.pdf

Here what I found so far as an amplifier topology:
http://www.linear.com/solutions/1183 
In my case the output of the straingauge will be very low; in the order of 1mV.

But there is a possibility I might use this device: http://www.microstrain.com/wireless/v-link-200 
Im not so familiar with terminology in datasheet much.

Do you think I would still need to implement the LT’s strain gauge amplifier if I buy this wireless device for these straingauges of 1mV level variation? I was wondering would noise be a problem at this signal level if I don't amplify.

Comment: I'd suggest you definitely need the strain gauge amplifier. Your wireless solution is +/-150 mV full scale ...your signal is down in the weeds.

Comment: +/-150 mV means the signal input variation should be minimum 150mV right? os is that the range and resolution issue? so better I use that LT's amplifier. But theres a simulation in their website which is different as: 100k resistor becomes 100ohm(maybe a mistake), supply becomes +-15V not single. Did you see that? Does the 100k set the gain of the amplifier in the schematic? thanks.

Comment: the wireless device unders specs it says: Differential: ±1.22 mV to ±156 mV DC (bridge completion factory-configurable)

Single-ended: ±2.56 V dc, ±5.12 V dc, ±10.24 V DC, 0 to 5.12 V dc, 0 to 10,24 V dc im kind of confused

Answer (score 0):

The manual is [here](http://www.microstrain.com/sites/default/files/applications/files/v-link-200_user_manual_8500-0063_5.pdf) and quick start guide is [here](http://www.microstrain.com/sites/default/files/applications/files/v-link200_qsg_8501-0073_0_0.pdf).

It appears that the full scale range is configurable using their software.
Minimum differential appears to be +/- 2 mV or maybe less.
ir IF this is correct and IF your strain gauge outputs about 1 mV max then the V-Link 200 should be all you need. A closer reading of the manual and a look at the software manual should clarify this.

Comment: T the output of the straingauge will be very low; in the order of 1mV. if the cables are longer than 10 m, i was thinking noise would be an issue. does the straingauge sensor's two output differential(mirrored) voltages?

Comment: After we deal with the cable length will you tell us it's in a locked filing cabinet in the basement and related to a bypass the Vogons are building :-)  ? ( [**HHGTTG**](http://www.clivebanks.co.uk/THHGTTG/THHGTTGradio1.htm) ). Why not put us out of our suspense and give us the complete question?  Adding information to the question is better than in comments. | Long cables and small signal levels are more noise prone. | Can you put the V-link near the gauge. Having the extra amplifier is liable to help rather than hinder. | The strain gauge bridge's output is a balanced differential signal.

Comment: I agree and I now opened a new question to make it clear:http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/296158/a-question-about-choosing-implementing-and-placing-a-strain-gauge-amplifier I would be glad to hear your opinion as well. Thanks